# Navigating in game loop

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I'm currently developing a UWP Win2D game. I need to navigate to a page in Update Event of CanvasAnimatedControl. I used the code below to do it on UI Thread. It does navigates but page freezes. No exception is thrown.

What is the correct way to navigate in Update event/Game Thread?

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    Page.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LevelResultPage));
});
```

Comment: Didn't you mean CanvasAnimatedControl instead of CanvasControl? You should try setting the CanvasAnimatedControl.Paused to true, so the Update event will not be raised when you are trying to navigate. https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/P_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasAnimatedControl_Paused.htm

Comment: Yes, it is CanvasAnimatedControl and setting canvasAnimatedControl.Paused as true before navigation works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Marian Dolinský mentioned in the question comments, the issue here is allowing the page to continue updating during the transition. Setting CanvasAnimatedControl#Paused to true will ensure it doesn't receive Update events and won't freeze.